# regex: Match ONLY second occurrence

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
<PLATFORM>.<ITEM1>.<ITEM2>.<METRIC_NAME>
```

And I would like to obtain the ITEM1 and ITEM2 information with a regex expression.

The ITEM1 I could get it with the following: `\.(.*?)\.`

But I'm having problems to obtain the ITEM2 of the pattern. Any help?

Comment: Add another capture group `\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)` ? Or for only `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` `\.<(.*?)>\.<(.*?)>` https://regex101.com/r/hbKOCR/1

Comment: Your items are overlapping at the dot. An idea to put the second dot into a lookahead to prevent skipping over: [`\.(<[^><]*>)(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/hpZJNe/1)